# Is the derivative both the best approximation of a value in relation to something else and how that value is changing with time?

Tags: derivatives

For example is we have a function m(x) that describes the distribution of mass along a line, so m(x) gives you the amount of mass at a certain length of the line. If we take the derivative of m with respect to x we get dm/dx or density. So if I were to plug in a x for the derivative I would get the best approximation of the density of the line at x as well as the rate at which the mass is changing with respect to x at that point?

Comment: The best linear approximation of $y$ near a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by $y \approx y_0 + y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$. It's not just the value of the derivative. The density per unit length at $x_0$ is technically exactly given by $m'(x_0)$, though.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your description of $m(x)$ is a bit vague when you say " the amount of mass at a certain length of the line."  Perhaps you have in mind a [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), so that $m(x) = 0$ for $x$ at one end of "the line" and $m(x)$ is the total mass present when $x$ is at the other end of the line.  In that case the derivative $m'(x)$ would be a density function which describes the concentration of mass along points of the line.